# How to drag a View to show another one that was underneath

Tags: android, view, drag, android-framelayout

How could I drag (only vertical down) my entire root view to show another one that it's suppose to be underneath? I need something similar to Android Notifications Bar behaviour that, when you drag it, it shows your notifications and if you drop it passing the middle of the screen it expands completely and it closes again. The difference with my case is that I have to move my View down when the upper View is expanded.

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout and change the position of the view you want to move at runtime.

Comment: But, can I change the position of the entire view with a linear movement and no notice the steps? How ?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking… if you don't want to notice the steps as you asked, you simply set the new position. If you want to notice them as in an animated slide-out, you will need to make multiple discrete small changes over time; I'm not sure if this can be done with Android's internal animation or if you'll need to create your own repeating timer to complete these steps in.

Comment: I don't want to notice, I mean I want to see the movement but like a linear movement, not to notice small movements. I tried to drag the view and then scroll but I didn't work. First, because I don't know how to make drag effect only in vertical and without shadow, and second because it's not scrolling at the position I set.